# In C# .NET, what directories can Directory.GetDirectories or Directory.GetFiles not get directories or files from, and Why?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-7

In C# .NET, certain directories passed to `Directory.GetDirectories` or `Directory.GetFiles` throw an exception. What is it exactly about those directories that cause it to be unable to read them?

```
simpletest1_test_exceptions_with_those_functions(@"C:\");
simpletest1_test_exceptions_with_those_functions(@"C:\windows");
```

The following function (simpletest1_test_exceptions_with_those_functions) I wrote to test GetDirectories and GetFiles, works fine, it shows what directories can't be accessed, though the question is why.

Note that the function intentionally has a lot commented out, because it has the capacity to browse a whole directory tree recursively but i've commented that so that it just does one level of the tree. And it would normally list all files and directories, but i've commented that. So that it only shows directories that the GetDirectories function can't access when the directory it can't access is passed as a parameter.

```
static void simpletest1_test_exceptions_with_those_functions(string sDir)
{
    // can't just have a try catch at the end otherwise it won't return.

    try 
    {

        Console.WriteLine("DirSearch..(" + sDir + ")");

        //Console.WriteLine(sDir);

        Console.WriteLine("files");
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
        {
            // Console.WriteLine(f);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("directories");
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            // testexceptionwiththosefunctions(d);
            // Console.WriteLine(d);

            try
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine(f);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("z Directory.GetFiles threw exception");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("some exception thrown");
    }
  
    
}
```

gives

```
DirSearch..(C:\)
files
directories
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is denied.
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\MSOCache' is denied.
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\Recovery' is denied.
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\System Volume Information' is denied.
-----
DirSearch..(C:\windows)
files
directories
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\windows\LiveKernelReports' is denied.
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\windows\Minidump' is denied.
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\windows\ModemLogs' is denied.
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\windows\Prefetch' is denied.
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\windows\Temp' is denied.
```

Out of those paths..   "Documents And Settings" is a junction, so fine it can't deal with being passed a junction.

(dir /a shows all directories whether hidden or system or read only, just all)

```
C:\>dir /a | find "Docu"
14/07/2009  06:08    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]

C:\>
```

All the other directories listed there aren't junctions though.

So it's not that it just can't work on junctions.

Also, I can CD into Documents and Settings, I can't into many of the other directories. I can CD into `C:\Windows\temp` though others I can't

```
C:\Windows>cd Temp

C:\Windows\Temp>cd ..

C:\Windows>cd LiveKernelReports
Access is denied.

C:\Windows>
```

Whether it's hidden or system or read only isn't relevant

For example this directory is not hidden or system or read only

```
C:\Windows>dir | find "Live"
14/07/2009  03:34    <DIR>          LiveKernelReports

C:\Windows>attrib LiveKernelReports
             C:\Windows\LiveKernelReports

C:\Windows>
```

It's not an issue of what is system or hidden, as Directory.GetFiles and Directory.GetDirectories have no problems on such directories.  I tried creating  c:\atest\hdir (where hdir is a hidden directory)  and c:\test\sdir  (where sdir is a system directory)

```
C:\atest>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4645-5DCE

 Directory of C:\atest

17/07/2020  02:45    <DIR>          .
17/07/2020  02:45    <DIR>          ..
17/07/2020  02:44    <DIR>          hdir
17/07/2020  02:45    <DIR>          rdir
17/07/2020  02:44    <DIR>          sdir
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  286,734,127,104 bytes free

C:\atest>attrib +h hdir

C:\atest>attrib +r rdir

C:\atest>attrib +s sdir

C:\atest>attrib sdir
   S         C:\atest\sdir

C:\atest>attrib hdir
    H        C:\atest\hdir

C:\atest>attrib rdir
     R       C:\atest\rdir

C:\atest>
```

I used this simpler function  to verify if specific paths(passed to GetFiles or GetDirectories) throw exceptions or not and the hidden/system/read only directories that I created do not throw exceptions.

It verified that the system/read-only/hidden has nothing to do with it.

```
static void test_exception_with_thosefunctions()
{
    string[] dirs=null;
    string[] files=null;
    string dirstr="";
    try
    {
        // dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Documents and Settings");
        dirstr = @"c:\atest\hdir";
        dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirstr);
        files = Directory.GetFiles(dirstr);

        dirstr = @"c:\atest\rdir";
        dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirstr);
        files = Directory.GetFiles(dirstr);

        dirstr = @"c:\atest\sdir";
        dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirstr);
        files = Directory.GetFiles(dirstr);

        // files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings");
        Console.WriteLine(dirs.Length);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //if(dirs!=null) Console.WriteLine(dirs.Length);
        //if(files!=null) Console.WriteLine(files.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

So there's clearly something about those paths I listed, that throw exceptions.. i'm wondering what is it about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple put, you don't have permissions to those directories.

Run (elevate) your app / command prompt as administrator will solve a lot of the issues.

Comment: For compatibility mountpoints (aka junctions) such as "Documents and Settings", everyone (S-1-1-0) is denied the right to list the directory. They only exist to be traversed to access subdirectories (e.g. `dir "C:\Documents and Settings\Public"`). It has nothing at all to do with the fact that they're mountpoints. It's just a function of the discretionary access control list set on the directory.

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks, that covers a lot, so now the only ones not accessible are "documents and settings", and "system volume information".  any idea why the  'system volume information" directory gives that error?

Comment: @ErykSun is there a command to show the "discretionary access control list" for a directory  so that shows that restriction on "documents and settings"

Comment: I think for system volume information  you might have to explicitly give yourself / user permission. never tried it though. This is a bit old and may not be relevant in later versions https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/309531/how-to-gain-access-to-the-system-volume-information-folder

Comment: @barlop, you can use icacls.exe or Sysinternals accesschk.exe.

Comment: @ErykSun  I just looked at the folder properties for "documents and settings", and it doesn't list "everyone" at all.  Also I looked at some random folders, and most of them don't list "everyone" either, though I can access those.

Comment: @barlop, `icacls "C:\Documents and Settings"` should have a deny entry for everyone (S-1-1-0), but the friendly name of the group gets localized (check sysinternals `psgetsid s-1-1-0`). Most folders do not grant access to everyone. Typically they grant access to groups such as "authenticated users" (S-1-5-11), system (S-1-5-18), administrators (S-1-5-32-544), and users (S-1-5-32-545).

Comment: @ErykSun thanks, does this tell you anything `C:\Windows\system32>icacls "c:\System Volume Information"
c:\System Volume Information NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F) `     ?

Comment: @barlop, generally no access is granted unless it's specifically granted by entries in the discretionary access control list (DACL). In the case of "C:\System Volume Information", only the SYSTEM group (S-1-5-18) is granted access. Generally only system services run in a SYSTEM process. You can run as SYSTEM via sysinternals psexec, e.g. `psexec -sid cmd.exe` and check `whoami` in the opened command prompt.

Comment: There are some common exceptions to the DACL rule. The owner of an object is implicitly granted `READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC` access to be able to read and modify the DACL, and SeChangeNotifyPrivilege, which all uses have, allows traversing a directory to its children even if no access is granted to the directory.

Comment: @ErykSun thanks, yes I see after the psexec exec line that ran cmd as system, then I can CD into and DIR on "system volume information" .  You can post that as an answer. mentioning re documents and settings, and mentioning system volume information

Answer (score 0):

I will leave TheGeneral's answer as accepted, it covers most of the directories  I mentioned, though it doesn't cover these two directories -  "documents and settings" and "system volume information".

I have posted this answer to cover what Eryk Sun mentioned in comment, which covers re those two directories.

TheGeneral's answer of running from an administrative cmd prompt 'cos some require administrative privileges, certainly answers many of those cases, though not all

```
C:\blah>ConsoleApp1.exe
adf
0
DirSearch..(C:\)
files
directories
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is denied.
z Directory.GetFiles threw exception
Access to the path 'C:\System Volume Information' is denied.
-----
DirSearch..(C:\windows)
files
directories
```

So that shows two directories still not being read even from an administrative cmd prompt.

The `C:\Documents and Settings` directory and the 'C:\System Volume Information' directory.

Eryk Sun mentions that "for compatibility mountpoints (aka junctions)  everyone (S-1-1-0) is denied the right to list the directory. They only exist to be traversed to access subdirectories (e.g. dir "C:\Documents and Settings\Public"). It has nothing at all to do with the fact that they're mountpoints. It's just a function of the discretionary access control list set on the directory."

Eryk mentions   "
icacls "C:\Documents and Settings" should have a deny entry for everyone (S-1-1-0), but the friendly name of the group gets localized (check sysinternals psgetsid s-1-1-0). Most folders do not grant access to everyone. Typically they grant access to groups such as "authenticated users" (S-1-5-11), system (S-1-5-18), administrators (S-1-5-32-544), and users (S-1-5-32-545)
"

And indeed  icacls "C:\Documents and Settings"  does show a deny entry for everyone

```
C:\Windows\system32>icacls "C:\Documents and Settings"
C:\Documents and Settings Everyone:(DENY)(S,RD)
                          Everyone:(RX)
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                          BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

So that leaves `C:\System Volume Information` as the remaining mystery.

Eryk mentions   "generally no access is granted unless it's specifically granted by entries in the discretionary access control list (DACL). In the case of "C:\System Volume Information", only the SYSTEM group (S-1-5-18) is granted access. Generally only system services run in a SYSTEM process. You can run as SYSTEM via sysinternals psexec, e.g. psexec -sid cmd.exe and check whoami in the opened command prompt."

and Eryk mentions "There are some common exceptions to the DACL rule. The owner of an object is implicitly granted READ_CONTROL and WRITE_DAC access to be able to read and modify the DACL, and SeChangeNotifyPrivilege, which all uses have, allows traversing a directory to its children even if no access is granted to the directory"

And indeed, if I run that psexec command `psexec -sid cmd.exe` so as to run cmd.exe as System user, then I can CD into and list the System Volume Information directory. And whoami shows that it is the system user.

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd "\System Volume Information"

C:\System Volume Information>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4645-5DCE

 Directory of C:\System Volume Information

26/12/2019  11:39        50,790,280 smartdb_Volume{f0f46b52-75c5-11e6-87ea-806e6
f6e6963}.sdb
18/07/2020  19:21         2,621,440 Syscache.hve
24/04/2020  02:39    <DIR>          Windows Backup
24/04/2020  16:06    <DIR>          WindowsImageBackup
               2 File(s)     53,411,720 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  289,325,735,936 bytes free

C:\System Volume Information>whoami
nt authority\system

C:\System Volume Information>
```